# how should I set "scopes" when creating ServiceAccountCredential FromServiceAccountData

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

I need to set the credentials scope to access [some APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch)
my code is like that

```
ServiceAccountCredential saCredential;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\work\ConsoleApp2\google_credentials\foo.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            saCredential = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(fs);
            
        }

        //saCredential.Scopes = new List<string> { "" };
        var accessToken = saCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
```

how can I set the scopes? now I get

> TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_scope", Description:"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.",

the Scopes property is read-only

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to do it like that

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(new List<string>() { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute" });
        var dataflowService = new DataflowService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
```